# Deauth all users on AP except yourself

Tags: nmap, mac-address, aircrack-ng

I am looking to create a small first project to further my self education into infosec. I will be putting this on my [Github](https://github.com/m4ttclendenen).

My idea is to create a script that automates the process of deauthing all users on my wireless network except myself ( the machine running the script ).

---

**GAMEPLAN**

1. Host discovery with nmap
2. Find mac addresses of associated clients
3. airodump to get mac address of AP (or I could just plug the mac in because I know it)
4. Deauth all users except the machine running the script
5. Back into managed mode and surfing the web

---

I understand that:

- all deauthed users would most likely immediately reconnect if the password is saved in their system
- during the process of the deauth my wireless card would be in monitor mode

**My overall question**: Is deauthentication plausible to where I could hog my own network?

---

Here are some links to other question I have asked on this site related to this project:

- [Wireless card simultaneously in monitor mode and managed mode?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108986/wireless-card-simultaneously-in-monitor-mode-and-managed-mode)

---

In replies, specific aircrack / nmap commands are not needed I just want to see if the idea concept is plausible?

Here is some documentation for users who are not yet aware of:

- [Host Discovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/how-to-find-live-hosts-on-my-network) with [NMAP](https://nmap.org/)
- [Simple Deauthentication](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication) with the [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) suite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather quick Google search for *"python wifi deauth"* reveals several results for your question.

WiFi Jammer seems to do the job:

> Continuously jam all wifi clients and access points within range. The
>   effectiveness of this script is constrained by your wireless card.
>   Alfa cards seem to effectively jam within about a block radius with
>   heavy access point saturation. Granularity is given in the options for
>   more effective targeting.

More infomration can be found at: https://github.com/DanMcInerney/wifijammer

Answer (score 1):

To answer "Deauth all users on AP except yourself". 
You could just add the following in your script:

- Get your MACID
- Remove your MACID from the discovered hosts list (e.g. grep exclude and write output to a new file, etc...)
- Deauth remaining MACID's in the file