# Wireless card simultaneously in monitor mode and managed mode

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I am looking to create a small first project to further my self education into infosec. I will be putting this on my [Github](https://github.com/m4ttclendenen).

My idea is to create a script that automates the process of deauthing all users on my wireless network except myself ( the machine running the script ).

I understand that:

- all deauthed users would most likely immediately reconnect if the password is saved in their system
- during the process of the deauth my wireless card would be in monitor mode

So, the solution to this could possibly be to simultaneously have my wireless card in monitor mode and managed mode. This way I could continuously deauthenticate all MACs ( except the machine running the script ) and "browse the web" at the same time.

Is this possible?

Or possible to add another wireless card via usb dongle and approach that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one card in monitor mode to deauth clients and capture traffic at the same time but the card itself can only be runned in one mode because the mode is kind of a binary option.

What you can do is using the internal card of your laptop in managed mode to connect to a network and the attached wifi card in monitor mode to capture and deauth clients. That would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hardware and OS.

It is perfectly doable to run, for example, a Linux machine with an ath5K/ath9K device which is supporting two virtual devices - one in managed mode and one in ad hoc mode. I've done this many times and it works flawlessly.

The reason why these cards work well is that much of their behaviour is controlled by the device driver. Other cards use a dedicated processor in the network interface and you are stuck with the behaviour the manufacturers built into the firmware that runs on the WNIC.