# DeAuth all AP's in range

Tags: aircrack-ng, deauth-attack

In a few days, we are going to be many friends that will gather together and play all night long using 6-7 APs.

How can I DeAuth/Disconnect everyone's connection, without being connected to their network?

Comment: Unplugging the APs

Comment: potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108953/deauth-all-users-on-ap-except-yourself

Comment: Why would you do that? How is this a security question?

Comment: The security implications are obvious to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mdk3` by typing `mdk3 --help`.

Then look for the selection for deauthing. I think the command is `mdk3 wlan0mon -d`. I'm not on Kali right now so I'm not sure, but this command should deauth every device within a range regardless of APs. Mdk3 deauths devices by channel.

Comment: I don't think monitor mode is required, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Using `airodump-ng` you can create a csv file containing all clients and APs detected. Feed this csv to `aireplay-ng` and deauthenticate them.

But if the APs in the question supports the [802.11w specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11w-2009), your deauthentication packets will be ignored.

Comment: Is there ways to deauth 802.11w?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no ways to fake deauth with 802.11w.

Answer (score 1):

Using [NetAttack2](https://github.com/chrizator/netattack2) you can de-auth **ALL** networks around you or you can select what you want to de-auth. This is how you set it up.

- In terminal type `git clone https://github.com/chrizator/netattack2`
- CD into the folder and run `chmod +777 netattack2.py`
- Run the python file with `python netattack2.py`
- A menu will popup saying what you want to do. Type in `6` or `7` depending what you want to do.